# odoo survey text label

Tags: odoo, odoo-survey

If I have to add a pure text label for the purpose of organizing the page into 2 sections, how should I do that? My page is broken up into few short sections and I wouldn't think it looks nice to split them up into pages.

I have tried to find examples but they are mainly describing how to build a short quiz format therefore i have run out of solutions. Should I do something on the css side or append more stuff on the survey.template file?

Could someone give me a simple example or short explanation on how should I add text labels on a odoo survey form?

Answer (score -1):

I have just solved it with some advice here and there. There could be other ways to do it but what I am doing now, as a simple guide, is: 
1) Inherit to your survey.template file and made the necessary adjustment, e.g. , then 
2) create an empty template id in your xml:  
3) in your py file, inherit survey.question and add your new type in 'type':

There you go!

Comment: add a question with a matrix and don't select any thing

Comment: thanks Murali, that's the direct way to do so. Not sure who down voted without providing useful feedback. Been waiting for answers for days. This kind of voting is what make things crap. However, using similar logic as above, u can create other interesting output such as generation of lines, extra space, or useful characters assignment without using needing any input. Do take note of the survey.results which will check for valid input. There, you will need to inherit and write your own conditional checks.